# Using JavaScript, how would I write 'if the next sibling has the specific class name xxx, do this, else do that'?

Tags: javascript

So far my code is as follows:

```
if(current.nextElementSibling) {
    // add --current to next sibling
    current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('about__slide--current');
} else {
    // add --current to start
    slides[0].classList.add('about__slide--current');
}
```

But as you can see it just checks if there is a sibling element and not if there is a sibling element with a specific name.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to create a slideshow background where the background that is visible is the one with the class 'about__slide--current'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `classList.contains()`

```
if (current.nextElementSibling && current.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("xxx")) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: For maximum confusion, the method is [`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) for a class list, not `.includes()`. I know, I hate it, too.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks. And it doesn't end there, `Set` uses `.has()`

Comment: Thanks for the response, don't know why but it broke the script :/

Comment: @Harrison Before or after fixing `includes` to be `contains`?

Comment: As I said, I hate it. Mostly every other place that has "a bunch of stuff" data structure provides a `.contains()` method. Not in JS because MooTools overwrote that, so the standard broke that library...so the standard had to change to the confusing `.includes()` and yet it's still `.contains()` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can match on a selector using [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches):

```
if(current.nextElementSibling && current.nextElementSibling.matches('.classname')) {
```